# How to debug a bitmap drawable assignment?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

I have an imageView in my Activity. I am trying to assign a bitmap image to it, but the UI isn't changed.

I want to debug it in Eclipse. How can I see the image which is assigned and the image which is replaced (default image)?

```
    ImageView iconView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);
    if (iconView != null && (item != null) && (item.icon != null)) {
        iconView.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        iconView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iconView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

the thread enters `iconView.setImageDrawable(item.icon);`

`icon` is `public Drawable icon`

Comment: if (iconView != null && (item != null) && (item.icon != null))  check this condition return true or not

Comment: Elad, are you sure item.icon isn't the default one?